# Form pairs from consecutive records for each distinct value of given field in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with the following data. "record_id" is the autoincremented primary key, "name" is indexed.

```
record_id name payload
1         a    x
2         b    y
3         c    y
4         b    z
5         a    z
6         a    w
7         b    y
8         c    x
```

How can I get pairs of consecutive rows for each "name"? I understand that I must join table to itself, but can't figure out how to join only the first of the rows with record_id greater than the one being processed. NULL-filled part after the last row for any "name" is important as well. Again, I understand that I probably must use LEFT JOIN for that.

```
1 a x 5 a z
5 a z 6 a w
6 a w NULL NULL NULL
2 b y 4 b z
4 b z 7 b y
7 b y NULL NULL NULL
3 c y 8 c x
8 c x NULL NULL NULL
```

I'm using MySQL pre-8.0, so I can't use window functions if that matters.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution that uses an outer join based on the corresponding record_id next-highest value.

```
select *
from t
left join t t2 on t2.record_id = (
  select record_id from t t2 
  where t2.name=t.name and t2.record_id > t.record_id 
  order by t2.record_id limit 1
) 
order by t.name, t.record_id;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d3c53e4d590fb985293adb0dc69410c7)

Comment: Stu, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I actually ended up using slightly edited query based on your proposal that seems to be much faster at least on my real data (~700K records)

    select *
    from t t1
    left join t t2 on t2.record_id = (
      select min(t3.record_id) from t t3
        where t3.name = t1.name and t3.record_id > t1.record_id
    ) 
    order by t1.name, t1.record_id;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.* from tbl t1 
left join tbl t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.record_id < t2.record_id
where not exists (select 1 from tbl t3 left join tbl t4 on t3.name = t4.name and t3.record_id < t4.record_id where t3.record_id = t1.record_id and t4.record_id < t2.record_id)
order by t1.name
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fc759d2f53fd7acbc23d786195fcc459)